# Get total count of records in WP GraphQL API

Tags: api

I'm using [this](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql) plugin to enable GQL API in WP.

Unfortunately, according to [this](https://github.com/wp-graphql/wp-graphql/issues/261) discussion, it's pretty limited and doesn't return total number of records for requested entity, e.g. list of users.

```
query MyQuery {
  users(first: 1) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
      cursor
    }
    pageInfo {
      endCursor
      startCursor
    }
  }
}
```

**Questions**

- Does anybody know how to get total count of records using this API?
- Is there any other way to implement GraphQL for WP using normal
  offset - limit pagination with total count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of figured it out. It's possible to extend existing schema with custom properties that will have their own callbacks-resolvers. Reference to custom types in the [documentation](https://docs.wpgraphql.com/extending/types/).

**Place this class to your functions.php**

```
class GQLRegister 
{
  var $itemName = null;
  var $itemProps = null;
  var $responseName = null;
  var $responseParams = null;
  var $responseParamsFunction = null;

  function __construct(
    $itemName, 
    $itemProps, 
    $responseName, 
    $responseParams, 
    $responseParamsFunction) {    
    $this->itemName = $itemName;
    $this->itemProps = $itemProps;
    $this->responseName = $responseName;
    $this->responseParams = $responseParams;
    $this->responseParamsFunction = $responseParamsFunction;
    add_action('graphql_register_types', [ $this, 'setItemType' ]);
    add_action('graphql_register_types', [ $this, 'setResponseType' ]);
    add_action('graphql_register_types', [ $this, 'setResponseParamsType' ]);
  }

  function setItemType() {
    register_graphql_object_type($this->itemName, [ 'fields' => $this->itemProps ]);
  }

  function setResponseType() {
    register_graphql_object_type($this->responseName, [
      'fields' => [
        'count' => [ 'type' => 'Integer' ],
        'items' => [ 'type' => [ 'list_of' => $this->itemName ]],
        'errors' => [ 'type' => [ 'list_of' => 'String' ]]
      ]
    ]);
  }

  function setResponseParamsType() {
    register_graphql_field('RootQuery', $this->responseName, [
      'type' => $this->responseName,
      'args' => $this->responseParams,
      'resolve' => $this->responseParamsFunction
    ]);
  }
}
```

**Call constructor of this class with the following parameters.**

```
new GQLRegister(
  'CustomUser',                               // define fields of a single object
  [
    'id' => [ 'type' => 'Integer' ],
    'name' => [ 'type' => 'String' ]
  ], 
  'CustomUserResponse',
  [                                           // define input parameters for new property
    'page' => [ 'type' => 'Integer' ],
    'count' => [ 'type' => 'Integer' ]
  ],
  function($root, $args, $context, $info) {   // extract data from DB in this method
    // $users = get_users($args);

    return [                                
      'count' => 1,                           // count($users) 
      'items' => [[ 'name' => 'Demo User' ]]  // $users
    ];
  }
);
```

Now, WPGraphQL shows new property on the query **customUserResponse** that can return the following structure.

```
{
  "data": {
    "customUserResponse": {
      "count": 1,
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Demo User"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```